# Find probability of tags coming together from given data

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, probability

I just need an algorithm to solve the following problem in an efficient manner.
I have tuples with combination of tags which usually come together.For example

```
    (python, django, flask, numpy),
    (java, spring),
    (mysql, sql, join),
    (javascript, angularjs, ajax, deferred)
```

Now I have two requirements.

1. I need to form different categories from given data.
2. Given a new tag  or tuple of tags, I need to find the probability of this tag coming together with all other distinct tags in data
       For example :

   ```
   Say new tuple is (nodejs, ajax)
       then the probabilities might be 
           (nodejs, ajax) - (javascript, angularjs, ajax, deferred) - .60
           (nodejs, ajax) - (mysql, sql, join) - .20
           (nodejs, ajax) - (java, spring) - .20
           etc
   ```

   How should I go about solving this.

Comment: If these tags are entirely new to the data set, then how do you have *any* basis from which to derive probabilities?

Comment: Yea there would be new tuples as such which would have some common tags with existing tuples.But my major concern is to  find the probability of the tags coming together.

Comment: I am not sure why the question has been down voted. It would be better if a reason is provided before down voting the question. It helps the author understand the shortcomings.

Comment: I can't speak for the others, but I suggest that you re-read the intro tour documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here -- and perhaps [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You've given example output that we cannot derive from the input; we have little idea what logic path you intend to use.  SO is for specific programming problems; your description so far is a general design problem that isn't well-defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,the best approach that solved this problem was basically `Apriori algorithm.` It will provide association rules for the transnational database (considering every row as a transaction).
Below is a link for a very simple tutorial with implementation.
http://aimotion.blogspot.com/2013/01/machine-learning-and-data-mining.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest treating this as a graph problem, tags are nodes and the number of occurence of say (tag1,tag2) is the weight of the edge between tag1 and tag2 nodes. You can possibly then generate recommended tags using nearest neighbour algorithm or even community detection (which tags are always co-mentioned together).

With a well constructed graph, enough initial data and some normalisation, I think it would be possible to output probability say of link between cluster1 =(tag1,tag2) with cluster2=(tag3,tag4,tag5).